# How use 1602 LCD with BBB over i2c?

Tags: c, i2c, beagleboneblack

I have a 1602A lcd and an I2C adapter(only 4bit support) for arduino and now i'd like to use it with my BBB in a Java (JNA) project.

In the LiquidCrystal I2C arduino lib use write4bit i2c command, but i don't find any  C/C++ bbb i2c which  contains this or writeBit. Every lib support writeByte only...

Is there any i2c lcd lib for bbb?
How can I send just 4 bit instead of Byte?

Thanks,
Kodam

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit-wise shift out that is redirected from the standard output (monitor) to the desired pin.  This functionality is found in stdio.h.  As for outputting the 4 bits instead of a byte, there are a couple of ways to do this.  Personally I would use a bit-wise shift out that would shift 4 bits only, the bit-wise shift operator in c is "<<" and ">>" depending on which direction you are shifting.

In summary, I would do a bit-wise shift to the standard output which is redirected to the i2c connection.